# object mutation is not expected from return function

Tags: javascript, oop

Could someone pelase explain the mutation behaviour below:

```js
function test () {
  let data = {}

  const run  = () => {
    console.log(data)
  }

  const update = () => {
    data = {}
  }

  return {
    container: {
      data
    },
    run,
    update
  };
}

const { container, run, update } = test();

update(); // run an update to reset value to {}

container.data.test = { result: 'test' }; // try to mutate the data

run(); // it will still return {} instead { data: {test: {result: 'test'}} }
```

I would expect to update the object would result mutate the data object inside the function., but looks like it's not the case, as if it created a new object.

Comment: Problem is when you do `data = {}` inside of the object it is replacing the object. The `container: {
      data
    },` is still referencing the old object. The container.data is not linked to the variable, it is linked to the object reference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ```
> const { container, run, update } = test();
> ```

This creates a new object which includes **the current value** of the `data` variable and assigns it.

> ```
> update(); // run an update to reset value to {}
> ```

This changes the value of the `data` variable to a new object.

> ```
> container.data.test = { result: 'test' }; // try to mutate the data
> ```

This mutates the object that was **originally** assigned to `data` and copied to the new object which was returned from `test()`.

It has no effect on the new object that is now the value of data.

---

In other words:

> ```
>   return {
>     container: {
>       data
>     },
>     run,
>     update
>   };
> ```

… copies the value of data and **does not** create a reference to the `data` variable.

Comment: copies the value of data means to create a shallow copy?

Comment: @user775735 — It doesn't matter if it is shallow or not. It's a copy and not a reference. JavaScript doesn't support references to variables.

Comment: how would you return a reference instead of copy? thanks for the answer and reply.

Comment: @user775735 — JavaScript **does not** support references to variables. If you want to mutate the object, then store the object and mutate it. You can't use a variable reference to do it (because there is no such thing as a variable reference in JS).

Answer (score 1):

When you call the `test()` function, `container.data` and `data` point to the *same* object:

```
container.data -----> {} <------ data
```

but after the following statement:

```
container.data.test = { result: 'test' };
```

`container.data` points to a different object:

```
container.data -----> { result: 'test' } 
data           -----> {}
```

but `data` still points to the empty object and this `data` variable is logged by the `run()` function.

Important thing to know here is that re-assigning to `container.data` *doesn't* re-assigns to the `data` variable as well.

Comment: The updated graph makes a lot more sense! I would like to upvote, but need 15 reputations... hope someone finds this answer valuable as well.